# Python Sets, Keys, and Dictionaries

Tags: python, function, dictionary, set, key

What I'm trying to do is ask the user for a name and then find out in how many clubs a person is, using sets and keys. I'm still new to dictionaries and sets, so I'm a bit confused with how to go about this. So far, I have this but it isn't working and giving me an error:

```
clubs = {'WSA': set(['Maria', 'Kennedy']), 'Reds': set(['Simon', 'Yamamoto']), 'Hikes': set(['Maria']), 'UVD': set(['Silver', 'Hasamov']) }

def member():
    name = raw_input('Name ==> ')
    i = 0
    memset = set([])
    nomemset = set([])
    while i <= len(clubs.keys()):
        for club in clubs:
            if clubs[clubs.keys()[i]][i] == clubs[clubs.keys()[i+1]][i]:
                memset.add(clubs.keys()[i])
                memset.add(clubs.keys()[i+1])
            else:
                nomemset.add(clubs.keys()[i])
                nomemset.add(clubs.keys()[i+1])
    print 'Member of: ', memset
    print 'Not member of: ', nomemset

member()
```

An example output would be this:

```
Name ==> Maria
Member of: set(['WSA', 'Hikes'])
Not member of: set(['Reds', 'UVD'])
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: This looks to me like it will infinitely loop, since you never change `i`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with comparing successive elements of `clubs.keys()` - @RafaelCardoso's complete rewrite looks right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making things more difficult than they are. Use

```
for key in dict
```

To iterate over keys, and `dict[key]` to get a key.
Also, to know if some `value` is in a `set`, use `if value in set` syntax. Then, your code would get much simpler:

```
clubs = {'WSA': set(['Maria', 'Kennedy']), 'Reds': set(['Simon', 'Yamamoto']), 'Hikes': set(['Maria']), 'UVD': set(['Silver', 'Hasamov']) }

def member():
    name = raw_input('Name ==> ')
    i = 0
    memset = set() #As recommended by TigerhawkT3
    nomemset = set()
    for (club, members) in clubs.items(): #As recommended by @DeGlopper
        if name in members:
           memset.add(club)
        else:
           nomemset.add(club)
    print 'Member of: ', memset
    print 'Not member of: ', nomemset

member()
```

Comment: Tiny quibble, you can use `for (club, members) in clubs.items()` to iterate directly over the key/value pairs.

Comment: You can initialize an empty `set` with just `set()` instead of `set([])`.

Comment: Good notice @PeterDeGlopper

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thanks for the suggestion, I added that to the code!